# Ninject: Bind same interface to two implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have a project called `Infrastructure`, which contains an interface `IRepository`

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified entity to the respository of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">The entity to add.</param>
    void Add(T entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the specified entity to the respository of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">The entity to delete.</param>
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

In my solution, i have two other projects

- *Application.Web*
- *Application.Web.Api*
- Infrastructure

Both projects, contains an implementation of the `IRepository` interface

```
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    // DbContext for Application.Web project
    ApplicationWebDbContext _db;
    public EFRepository(ApplicationWebDbContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    public void Add(T entity) { }
    public void Delete(T entity) { }
}

public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    // DbContext for Application.Web.Api project
    ApplicationWebAPIDbContext _db;
    public EFRepository(ApplicationWebAPIDbContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    public void Add(T entity) { }
    public void Delete(T entity) { }
}
```

Both implementations works with different `DataContexts`.

How can I bind this in ninject?

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    // bind IRepository for `Application.Web` project
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Application.Web.EFRepository<>));

    // bind IRepository for `Application.Web.Api' project
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Application.Web.Api.EFRepository<>));    
}
```

Comment: Is there some criteria when each of the repositories is to be used?

Comment: I'm afraid not. They just use the same interface, so i don't have to duplicate IRepository interface for each project i have

Comment: And how should Ninject know which of the two implementations it should use when you request a repository? Should it pick one at random?

Comment: That was my question..i think that it may be a way of achieving this somehow

Comment: ??? There needs to be some criteria which one to pick, otherwise it would make no sense to have two implementations. Formulate this criteria and than you can be helped. One example of such a criteria could be: "If the class that requires the repository is defined in the assembly `Application.Web.Api`, use implemenetation `Application.Web.Api.EFRepository<T>`." Another criteria could be: "If the class that requires the repository is instantiated from the API process, use `Application.Web.Api.EFRepository<T>`."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are [**several appoaches**](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) to resolve such situations

#### Named binding

Simplest, just provide name for dependency:

```
kernel
        .Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
        .To(typeof(WebApiEFRepository<>))
        // named binding
        .Named("WebApiEFRepository");
```

And resolve it using this name. Name cound be found in configuration: `web.config` for example:

```
var webApiEFRepository = kernel.Get<IRepository<Entity>>("WebApiEFRepository");
```

#### Contextual binding

Find from [injection context](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) what type to bind. **In your example based on target namespace**

```
kernel
    .Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .To(typeof(WebDbRepository<>))
    // using thins binding when injected into special namespace
    .When(request => request.Target.Type.Namespace.StartsWith("Application.Web"));
```

Get dependency from kernel:

```
// WebDbRepository<> will be injected
var serice = kernel.Get<Application.Web.Service>();
```